# Duda con css y html en topnav

Tags: html, css

**Buenas, tengo un  inconveniente donde se me redimensiona el `topnav` y no entiendo porqué si en ambos lados está exactamente igual.

**Home:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Sobre mi:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por algún motivo se me achica el `topnav` en **Sobre mi**

Este es el `css` que tengo hecho:

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .topnav {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      color: #fff;
      padding: 12px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      margin: 5px 2px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* Para el elemento sobre mi */
    .items {
      width: 69px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 5px 2px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .navbar a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FraBa Soft Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navigation-header.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="topnav">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-fw fa-instagram"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></a>
        <a href="sobre_mi.html" class="fa items">Sobre mi</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .topnav {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      color: #fff;
      padding: 12px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      margin: 5px 2px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* Para el elemento sobre mi */
    .items {
      width: 69px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 5px 2px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .navbar a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FraBa Soft Sobre mi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navigation-header.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="topnav">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-fw fa-instagram"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <a href="index.html" class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa items">Sobre mi</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Alguien me explica que estoy haciendo mal? Probablemente en el código no se vea bien, pero si abren las imágenes se puede observar bien lo que digo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presiona `Crtl+0`(0 de tu teclado numérico) para reestablecer el zoom de tu Chrome en la pestaña "index". el error no es de código, simplemente aumentaste el zoom del navegador en dicha pestaña, el tamaño real de tu código está en "Sobre mi"

Comment: Era exactamente eso, muchísimas gracias